# Ubuntu vm guest not working with full resolution

Tags: 14.04, vmware

The station was working very well until yesterday when I extended the HD size. I don't think it is related. 
I tried to uninstall vm-tool and re-install it again and I checked the services they are working. Still I can't get to the full resolution and I'm receiving this message every time I run the machine.

> "the virtual machine could not be changed to the selected monitor
>   layout."

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly your problem: extended the HD size! There was the same problem under my debian 8.7. After resizing my HD with GParted I get those error message from VMware. I tried to reinstall either open-vm-tools and VMware-tools but still with the same error after login to KDE and other GUIs.

Then I installed open-vm-tools to a snapshot without the resized HD and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After extend the HD size with GParted the same appears on my guest Debian VM. 
In vmware.log it's have:

```
TOOLS Resolution_Set failed: failure of the transport layer
```

But this works for me:

Open your .vmx with the text editor and remove all svga.* entries.

Change the vmotion.checkpointFBSize  to "33554432" (my size was the same)

Source: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/548073